# How to set up ReactJS in Rails without using preexisting gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Is there a way I can set up ReactJS in Rails without using preexisting gems, such as react-rails?

Answer (score 2):

Just like any javascript libs, you can just download the [source](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html) and copy it into your javascripts folder (preferably vendor/assets/javascripts). And then in application.js:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

Comment: Hi Hoang, I've tried that before, and for some reason, I keep getting errors for `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. I believe it's JSX related, but I don't know who to fix it.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to do `//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.` to get the JS files. You can place all of the files into vendor's directory and still be able to call files from it the way you would if they were located within the actual assets/javascript. Just a side note.